# How to checkout only part of file from another local branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

Let's say I have two local branches `master` and `slave`. Did some work on `master` and committed changes.

Now I want include only part of file from my `master` to `slave`.

I do know that how to include whole file.

`` git checkout `slave` 
git checkout `master` -- <file> ``

But that doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout `slave` 
mv file file.slave
git checkout `master` -- <file>
mv file file.master
// now munge file.slave with file.master parts you want
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. But there should be a better solution using only `git`.

Comment: Try an interactive rebase of master onto slave and edit the commit of interest.

Comment: Never mind I found a solution. `git checkout -p master -- <file>`. No I can choose what to include. Thanks anyway.